Is every subring of an algebra over a field $ k $ also an algebra over $ k $?
Let $k$ be a field, and $A$ a finite-dimensional algebra over $k$.
If $A \cong B \times C$ as rings, then we can conclude that $B$ and $C$ are algebras over $k$. Since $B \cong eAe$, where $e$ is a central idempotent in $A$, it is easy to verify that $eAe$ is a vector space over $k$, and thus $B$ is an algebra over $k$.
Now the question arises: if $D$ is a subring of $A$, can we conclude that $D$ is an algebra over $k$? In other words, is $D$ a vector space over $k$? Intuitively, it doesn't seem correct, but I haven't found a counterexample yet.

It is not even true when the algebra is $k.$

For example when the algebra $k=A=\mathbb Q,$ and $D=\mathbb Z.$

There is only one case where this is true: $k\cong \mathbb F_p.$

These are answers to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.
